# Passing string from native module to react native

Tags: react-native

I create a native module for android (in kotlin language)

```
class TestModule(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext) : ReactContextBaseJavaModule(reactContext) {
    override fun getName(): String {
        return "TestModule"
    }

    @ReactMethod
    fun testing(): String{
        return "my modules"
    }

}
```

I then registered this module in the ModulesPackages and add it to MainApplication.tk as instructed at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html

in App.js

```
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native'
const TestingModule = NativeModules.TestModule;
type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {

    alert(TestingModule.testing());

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}> test</Text>
      </View>

    );
  }
}
```

After running this, I expect to get the alert with the text "my modules", but I got alert with text "undefined"

I can't figure out what I did wrong. I did not see any error or complain when I run react-native run-android.

Any suggestion what I did wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make communication between native module and js module, you should invoke callback, promise or use event. In your case, the `testing` function could be change like

```
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback;

...

@ReactMethod
fun testing(callback: Callback): Void{
    callback.invoke("my modules")
}
```

**Edit**

you should pass a callback in js file in this case:

```
testCallback = (name) => {
    console.log(name);
}

componentDidMount() {
    TestingModule.testing(this.testCallback);
}
```

Comment: it does not seems to work. Without changing the app.js, I got the error "...got 0 arguments, expected 1". If I put a variable, so I have alert(TestingModule.testing(testing)) , I got the error "The callback getCurrentAppState() exists in module AppState, but only one callback may be registered to a function in a native module" .

Comment: you must pass function to that native module when calling @Denvi, I've made an edit for my answer

Comment: Thanks, This works for the console. But is there anyway I can assigned that callback, naming "TestModule" string to a variable to display on the UI? Whatever I do, I can get that value on the console, but I do not know how to assign it to a variable for displaying on the UI